# mysql password command line option --pasword="" fails but -p prompt succeeds?

Tags: mysql, bash

Scratching my head on this one.

I can connect to mysql using the `-p` option for password authentication

```
kevzettler@kevs-mbp-3 radcade-wordpress % mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 21
Server version: 5.7.40 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> \q
Bye
```

However when I try using the extended `-password` option it consistently gets Access denied rejected.

```
kevzettler@kevs-mbp-3 radcade-wordpress % mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -password='password'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.24.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

Is there some hidden security option rejecting the commandline password?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes.   (An alternative you might consider https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Comment: The option is `--password`, not `-password` or `--pasword` ... as you appear to be using ... based on what you wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long option must be prefixed with two dashes.

Like this:

```
--password='xyzzy'
```

Not like this:

```
-password='xyzzy'
```

With one option, it is literally the `-p` short option, followed by the password string `assword=xyzzy`. The short option has one dash prefix.

In MySQL, the short `-p` option requires no space between the option character and the password string. This is because `-p` followed by a space means to prompt for the password interactively.